# Specific version of cookbook chef kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I am trying to get a chef cookbook to run. I need version `1.7.2` of the cookbook to run with current at `1.7.3`.

I am currently trying to do, `recipe[nginx::default@1.7.2]` but it wont't work. This is in a runlist in my `.kitchen.yml` file.

I found an other source on here that showed the exact same thing I had, I can't seem to find the link but it was someone mentioning they had it from their notes.

As for version to which I am running, it would be the lastest one since it is a clean install last week.

Answer (score 0):

You could put that in your `metadata.rb` dependencies:

```
depends 'nginx', '1.7.2'
```

We generally recommend against exact pins though, as it can either bit-rot quickly or be hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, reason for exact version is someone did an update to the latest but didn't do it right. So need previous version. It should be solved today.